# Visual Studio 2013 Breakpoint Issue with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, I can't set a breakpoint in `@functions` when using **Visual Studio 2013**. Here's an example:

[image: VS2013]

However, the same kind of breakpoint works in **Visual Studio *2012***:

[image: VS2012]

- If you move the `@functions` block up to the top of the razor page in **VS2013** you ***can*** set a breakpoint in `@functions` once again.
- You *cannot* set a breakpoint in `@functions` if the block is somewhere in the HTML.

**Anyone know why? Maybe a bug?** This is a big inconvenience if you're migrating an web app from MVC4 or earlier where `@function` blocks appear in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a known issue. See reported bug in MS Connect.

Description:

"*After my upgrade to VS 2013, I am no longer able to debug javascript within MVC razor files.* "

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807088/unable-to-debug-javascript-from-the-vs-2013-ide-unable-to-set-breakpoint

Comment: I have the same issue.  But not just in @functions...all javascript.  Very annoying, back to Chrome debuggin...

Answer (score 2):

I had all of the same issues with "This not a valid location for a breakpoint", and I also had no code highlighting or intellisense on any of the Razor code.  None of the solutions I could find resolved it.  Primarily because my issue was due to a really dumb oversight on my part, but just in case anyone finds themselves here and have made the same mistake, I thought I'd share it.

If you did not physically create the view yourself in Visual Studio, like if it was created with a NuGet package (Umbraco in my case), or if you opened an existing solution that isn't yours...The view may not be included in the project.  You may see something like this
[image]

Notice that the Homepage.cshtml file is in there and I can edit it, compile it, render it etc.  But I could not insert a breakpoint anywhere.  Right clicking on the file and Selecting "Include In Project" was the fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was Excluding the file then Including it again. Picked up the Breakpoints straight away.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

What helped me overcome this issue was enabling the "ASP.NET" option in the project-properties. See the screenshot: [image: Screenshot from Project Properties]

Comment: me neither even after restarting vs2013